# EditText.getText on a null object reference

Tags: android, edittext, alertdialog

estou tentando adicionar registros no Firebase Realtime Database, através de um AlertDialog, porem os componentes EditText não deixam eu abstrair as informações dos componentes.

Segue abaixo o trecho do java..

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            //Alerta para alterar informações do usuario.
            Snackbar.make(view, "Adicionando um novo registro", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Registro", null).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (MainActivity.this).getLayoutInflater();
            builder.setTitle("Registro");
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fab_registro,null));
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    EditText data , nome , idade , horaExame , procedimento ,qtsPeliculas ;
                    nome = findViewById(R.id.registro_nome);
                    data = findViewById(R.id.registro_data);
                    horaExame = findViewById(R.id.registro_hora);
                    idade = findViewById(R.id.registro_idade);
                    qtsPeliculas = findViewById(R.id.registro_peliculas);
                    procedimento = findViewById(R.id.registro_procedimento);
                    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Paciente");
                    String child = nome.getText().toString();

                    myRef.child(child).child("hora_exame").setValue("enrique");
                    myRef.child(child).child("procedimento").setValue("toráx");
                    myRef.child(child).child("peliculas").setValue("3");

                    myRef.child(child).child("data").setValue("23456");
                    myRef.child(child).child("idade").setValue("42");
                    myRef.child(child).child("nome").setValue("enriqeu");

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);
            builder.create();
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

Esse é o Logcat do erro

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.getText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.martel.unimedradiologia_controledeestoque.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:164)
```

o xml do layout tá tudo certo, tanto o tipo quanto o id.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, eu tô achando estranho o edittext sendo instanciado no clique do botão
(EditText nome... nome = findBiewById(...)). O convencional é fazer o instanciamento de cada view no onCreate.

Outra coisa estranha no bloco de código que você enviou é que não foi feito o casting (o correto seria: EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(...)).

Reveja essas questões que provavelmente estão relacionadas com a causa deste problema.

Comment: Sim, esse trecho está dentro de onCreate. mesmo criando no início do onCreate (fora do botão) dá esse problema. e a respeito do casting não é obrigatório usar, porém tentei com ele tbm e não foi.

Comment: Essas views são do layout que está sendo inflado? Esse layout que está sendo inflado é o mesmo utilizado na MainAcitivity?

Comment: não, criei um layout XML só pro fab no caso

Comment: Teria como você tá postando o layout da MainActivity?

Comment: Nesse momento não, mas. postarei assim que der, posso adiantar que é apenas um ListView com o fab no canto.

Comment: Tranquilo.
Humm, então esse edittext está em um outro layout que não é invocado pela MainActivity? Ou ele está no layout do adapter no ListView?

Comment: ele é inflado no onClick do fab

Comment: Sim, o onclick do fab infla um AlertDialog com um layout personalizado, aí no método setPositiveButton que eu tento abstrair em string os valores dos componentes e enviar pro firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Você estava tentando recuperar o objeto na sua `MainActivity`, porem esses objetos não foram inflados no XML da `MainActivity` você tem que usar a referencia da `View` inflada para recuperar os objetos referenciados pelo `R.id.`.

Bastou criar uma variável da sua `View` customizada que estava passando para o `AlertDialog` e usar o `findViewById` desse referencia criada e não da `MainActivity`

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            //Alerta para alterar informações do usuario.
            Snackbar.make(view, "Adicionando um novo registro", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Registro", null).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (MainActivity.this).getLayoutInflater();
            builder.setTitle("Registro");
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fab_registro,null);
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    EditText data , nome , idade , horaExame , procedimento ,qtsPeliculas ;
                    nome = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.registro_nome);
                    data = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.registro_data);
                    horaExame = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.registro_hora);
                    idade = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.registro_idade);
                    qtsPeliculas = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.registro_peliculas);
                    procedimento = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.registro_procedimento);
                    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Paciente");
                    String child = nome.getText().toString();

                    myRef.child(child).child("hora_exame").setValue("enrique");
                    myRef.child(child).child("procedimento").setValue("toráx");
                    myRef.child(child).child("peliculas").setValue("3");

                    myRef.child(child).child("data").setValue("23456");
                    myRef.child(child).child("idade").setValue("42");
                    myRef.child(child).child("nome").setValue("enriqeu");

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);
            builder.create();
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Se continuar dando esse erro, cheque suas IDs no XML layout/fab_registro.xml se estão todas lá